# Unregister Android Azure push notifications

Tags: android, azure, notifications

I was trying to "update" the register( for example when the user is not logged in, and then instead of a new register for the same user in a logged in mode just wanted to update the register). But didn't find an option for it, so I've decided to do it with register - unregister.
I can't seem however to unregister successfully. It just doesn't unregister. 
Right now I'm trying to register and unregister right away just until I make the unregister work :

I call this at the beginning:

```
...
String[] args = new String[]{"000"};
args = ArrayUtils.addAll(args, "111");
args = ArrayUtils.addAll(args, "111");
register(args);
...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void register(final String[] args) {
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                try {
                    String regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    String regRes = hub.register(regid, args).getRegistrationId();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                unregister1();
            };

        }.execute(null, null, null);

    }

public void unregister1()
        {
            new AsyncTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                    try 
                    {
                        //gcm.unregister();
                        hub.unregister();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG","error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            };
        }
```